# Database schema naming conventions and common mistakes?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYkV6.png) :

I'm asked to design a relational database to keep data to answer clinic operation queries such as:

● List the patient appointments for each doctor for a given date.

● When a patient rings to make an appointment, give the available time slots for a given date.

● Retrieve the address of patients to send notices via mail services.

I have one database schema of one relation as shown below, but I was wondering whether there were any mistakes I've made?

**ABC(doc-name, doc-gender, registration_num, qualification, pat-name, pat-gender, DOB, address, phone-num, appoint-date, appoint-time, type)**

Is the use of words such as date and the use of hyphens generally discouraged? Are there any other weaknesses in my design?

Thank you

Comment: Grant goes into more detail below, but you don't have any relations in what you've posted.  In order to have a "relation" you have to have at least two tables.

Comment: @Brian A table is a relation is a representation of a business relationship/association--as in "the relational model" & "the E-R model". FKs are frequently wrongly called "relationships" & sometimes more wrongly called "relations" by presentations/methods/tools that don't understand the relational model. But they are not.

Comment: Hi. Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Say what you were supposed to do & reference/quote your textbook & show your work following it, or you are just askng us to rewrite it & apply it.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 1):

So, that's not a schema or a design. Not for a relational database, which, based on the tags for the question, is what you're looking for. That's the storage definition for an ID/Value style of database. If you're looking for actual relational storage, you should be building out those relationships through the process of normalization.

For example, let's start at the beginning with doc-name (I am personally not crazy about using hyphens, but it's not a showstopper, so at least on that note, be sure whichever RDBMS you're working with supports them in the name and then you're good to go). If we think about this just from a data entry stand point, we don't want to have to type in the name of the doctor every time we use that doctor. Instead, we'd want to pull that from a list. So, clearly, we can break that apart from the rest of the information. There is the beginning of our normalization process. We can also easily note the fact that a patient is likely to have more than one appointment. Under the current structure, we'd have to re-enter every bit of patient information prior to the appointment. There's another place where we'd break this apart.

There is tons more to this simple example that could be split out and normalized.

I'd suggest you read up on data normalization. My favorite teacher on the subject is Louis Davidson. [Here's his book on the topic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484219724). Read that and then try  to readdress the situation you're facing.

I'm assuming this isn't just homework. If it is, currently, I'd give you an "F". If it isn't, you should track down someone to give you hand with this database design. You won't be able to quickly read Louis' book on the topic and turn around even a rough working design in any reasonable period of time.

Comment: The given DDL *is* a relational design that can hold the relation/table value that the given illustration can be taken to give. (Ignoring column name differences.) Of course it is not a "good" design. But that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have to second what Grant said, this is not a relational design at all.
Stop and ask yourself for example what happens if Steven Arrow has to take an afternoon off and update his schedule. You need to be very careful updating the database lest you reassign all his patients.

Spending a total of 5 minutes on this, I see at the very least:
A Doctors table, a Patients Table, and probably a table of open appointment times (which btw, is a bit harder than you think, so you have to give some thought how to handle that and some reading up on tables for scheduling).

That's for starters. I might break out Patients phone numbers to its own table. Why? Well how many columns do you want have for phone numbers? 1? What if they have a work AND home number?  Or a Work and Cell and Home? And more.

The concept you're looking for is normal forms. You don't need to go overboard, but generally 3NF is about right.

Comment: Would this be better? 

DOC(name, gender, registration_num, qualification)

PAT(name, gender, DOB, address, phone_num)

APPOINT(date, time, type)